# Pi 4 / Raspbian Lite HDMI Output Shared Across 2 Screens

Tags: chromium, raspbian-lite, kiosk

I am booting a Pi 4 running the latest version of Raspbian Lite into Chromium kiosk mode and outputting the display to 2 monitors.

I have successfully hooked up the 2 monitors, but the displays are mirrored showing the same output on each screen.

*My goal is to have an "extended" screen where Chromium goes fullscreen and is stretched equally across the 2 monitors.*

To this point, I have made minimal configuration updates. I have used NOOBS to install Raspbian Lite. I then installed X Server, Openbox and Chromium. The Pi boots directly into Chromium in kiosk mode and loads the webpage as expected.

I have edited the Openbox config like:

```
xset s off
xset s noblank
xset -dpms

setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

chromium-browser --disable-infobars --kiosk 'https.myurl.com'
```

And added a `.bash_profile` with:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && startx
```

Comment: I'd start by researching `xrandr`, eg. https://magnatecha.com/dual-monitors-with-openbox-and-xrandr/ (not a solution but an intro to the concept).   My first goal would be a continuous display, ie., one where Chromium probably comes up on only one screen. Using a mouse might help.

Comment: The title of your question is wrong. A RPi 4B cannot run with Raspbian Stretch. It has to use Raspbian Buster.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fiddle with the config files.

Run Screen Configuration which has options to configure both screens. (This is basically a front end to xrandr.)

This is a GUI but AFAIK the only way to configure multiple screens.

If you hadn't wasted space with NOOBS you would have plenty of room for Raspbian with Desktop.

Comment: The comment about NOOBS is irrelevant to the answer and unnecessary personal opinion